# twitter login TLS SSL issue

Tags: c#, twitter, tls1.2, twitter-oauth

I am developing an application that uses Twitter login as one of the ways to register an account and a few days ago it just suddenly stopped working. It uses OAuth as the authentication method. I've checked the keys and they haven't changed, has anyone had experience with this? I'm now getting this error:

[image]

[image]

I am using below configuration also

```cs
var twitterOptions = new TwitterAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = "twitter",
    Caption = "Twitter",
    SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,

    ConsumerKey = twitterConfig.ConsumerKey,
    ConsumerSecret = twitterConfig.ConsumerSecret,

    // NOTE: It seems that the certificate values embedded in the OWIN Twitter Middleware package are no longer valid.
    // This shows up in the form of an "AuthorizationException" whenever someone tries to click on the "Login with Twitter" button,
    // so we'll have to keep an eye on this in case Twitter invalidates the certs again
    BackchannelCertificateValidator = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.CertificateSubjectKeyIdentifierValidator(new[]
        {
            "A5EF0B11CEC04103A34A659048B21CE0572D7D47", // VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G2
            "0D445C165344C1827E1D20AB25F40163D8BE79A5", // VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
            "7FD365A7C2DDECBBF03009F34339FA02AF333133", // VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
            "39A55D933676616E73A761DFA16A7E59CDE66FAD", // Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
            "‎add53f6680fe66e383cbac3e60922e3b4c412bed", // Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3
            "4eb6d578499b1ccf5f581ead56be3d9b6744a5e5", // VeriSign Class 3 Primary CA - G5
            "5168FF90AF0207753CCCD9656462A212B859723B", // DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server C‎A
            "B13EC36903F8BF4701D498261A0802EF63642BC3" // DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
        })
};

app.UseTwitterAuthentication(twitterOptions);
```

Comment: Issus has nothing to do with OAUTH.  TLS is performed before HTTP request is sent using certificates.  Client request TLS version 1.2 or 1.3 (SSL, TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1 are obsolete).  Server sends a certificate block with names of usable certificates.  Client then looks up the certificates in the stores.  TLS is failing.  Either version encryption mode, or common certificate is wrong.

Comment: @jdweng Could you pls confirm below points first - server here would be twitter and client would be our backend application code base , right ? and Server sends a certificate block with names of usable certificates (can we check what all usable certificates twitter is sending to our application ) and what would you mean by common certificate and version encryption mode , could you provide more insight how to check it

Comment: What version of Windows are you running on? there were changes a few months ago when older Windows Server versions moved out of support for current TLS versions.

Comment: See WIKI : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security?force_isolation=true.  Your client stores has to have one of the certificates names that server sends in certificate block.  Client app can load a certificate and then the loaded certificate would have to match a certificate name that is sent from server.  The certificate is never sent between client and server (only the name).  The certificate must be loaded in both the client and server and the encryption mode in the certificate has to be valid for version of TLS being used (see wiki).

Comment: @AndyPiper : The windows security push in June 2020 disabled SSL, TLS 1.0, and TLS 1.1.  That was two years ago.  It wasn't a few months ago.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I believe a Twitter server-side update in around May removed insecure ciphers that used to be supported on Windows Server 2008 and possibly some in Windows Server 2012, which is why I asked about the specific version. Either way, those are very old Windows releases.

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions for this is to place this somewhere in the startup code of your application:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: I tried using it in window service application , it still didn't worked .  `public static void Main(string[] args)
        { ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
 HostFactory.Run(x =>{x.Service<Service>(s =>{
 s.ConstructUsing(name => new Service());
 s.WhenStarted(svc => svc.Start());
 s.WhenStopped(svc => svc.Stop());
 });
 x.RunAsLocalSystem();
 x.SetDescription("ECN SSO Authentication Service");
 x.SetDisplayName("ECN AuthService");
 x.SetServiceName("AuthService");});`